# Tons of People Cheating on Exams which hampers my grade

Tags: grades, cheating, online-learning

To give you some context we recently had our final exams and I barely managed to cross the threshold to get a 10 GPA in the course. I later found out tons of people had cheated on that course and cruised through it. These groups of people formed towards the end of the semester but now I'm worried they'll do this again from the beginning of the next semester which will make it even more harder for people who don't. Even our teacher acknowledged that cheating has happened but can't take any actions due to 2 reasons majorly, numerical based questions have more or less the same way to solve and identical calculations and proofs are bound to be similar in a class of 600-700 students.

To sort of counter this for some reason the professors decided to make the paper more difficult and more lengthy by adding more parts to each questions compared to previous years but this only made it more difficult for people who're attempting it honestly as when 5 people group together even if each person handles 1-2 questions they can easily finish them off.

Now I know the standard BS that focus on learning and I do but grades do matter, they matter everywhere and they matter in the long run as well and I'm genuinely worried that over time this will hamper by grades over time. Proctored exams also don't really make a difference as they can't really look at what a person is doing with like his other devices and there are tons of excuses people have. I even know a guy who tried solving a question got some wrong values then copied the second part correctly from some other person. He got through by making up some excuse with the TA.

How can I approach the professors or the administration or even try to suggest ways to make the process more fair, I don't want to snitch on others specifically and neither do I know everyone who cheats, I only know some people who would mention this at times and even invited me

Comment: There is no question here, just a rant.

Comment: I'm sorry I totally forgot to ask my question i ended up just writing the context @BryanKrause I've added the main question at the end

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Other students can easily cheat on a test and the grading system is relative - should I cheat, and what else can I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147978/other-students-can-easily-cheat-on-a-test-and-the-grading-system-is-relative-s)

Comment: Isn't 10 the max?

Comment: @Buffy yup I got it this time because we are all new here and didn't have friend circles till like the end of the semester. So people cheated in the later half more while I worked consistently over the semester so my requirements from the final exams were less, but even still it was difficult to cross that since the exam level drastically increased. I'm more concerned since now these groups already exist they'll most probably share this from the very start of the next semester

Comment: First, "I heard that tons of people are cheating" is not very confincing. Imagine having to take action on that basis. You need more. It does not have to be proof that will stand in court, but it needs to be much more than what you said here. Second, you need to think about what you want them to do.

Comment: Do you have any proof (e.g. message, email) of their invitation to you to cheat with them?

Comment: @MaartenBuis The people who approached me told me that almost everyone is doing that when I turned them down. A close friend of mine who would almost always fail in the weekly tests all of a sudden aced the end semester exams which were after a week and he's the guy who was caught in that last bit

Comment: @GoodDeeds It was over call so I don't but even if I did the issue is if i share the snapshot they can easily get away by saying it was a joke but I'll be isolated by all the circles in college

Comment: Is your grading relative, i.e., do the scores of others influence your grade in any way?

Comment: @GoodDeeds In this course No but in other courses yes so if people are cheating here I think it's safe to presume they'll be doing that in other places too

Comment: @cag51 Yeah it does deal with some aspects but not all of them

Comment: Umm why was this question closed? I feel it has a background as well as a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get perfect marks (10), then the cheaters don't really hamper your grade. They don't, in the short term, inconvenience you at all. You are doing the work to learn and your marks show that. All is well. Long term, you might be competing in some marketplace with unethical people, of course.

I suggest two options. Direct and indirect.

The direct action is to find a few people in the same situation and make a joint appeal to administration. They are likely aware of it, of course. But you can point out "how" people are cheating without getting in to the "who". Ask for steps to be taken. No guarantee of success. But this is something for group, not individual action.

The indirect action is to spend some effort becoming known to faculty for your hard work and skills so that they are assured that you are there to learn, not cheat. If you are successful at this, then you will have access to good support in those marketplaces, including, especially good letters of recommendation.

I highly recommend the second (indirect) action. I only point out the first.

Comment: More or less I also want to go with the second option as the first one would make it more difficult for me over the next few years. Thanks!